# Why can't I access a protected method?

Tags: java

I have a question about the protection mechanism from different packages in JAVA. What I can not understand is, why this method call not work!

```
package A;
class A 
{
    protected void method(){}; 
}

package B;
import A.A;

class B extends A
{

}

class Main extends A
{
    B b = new B();
    b.method();// ERROR: method() has protected access in Package1.A
}

Why!!
```

Comment: First of all, there are a lot of problems here. Why is the `Class` used instead of `class`?

Comment: @Kon yes, I modify that, but that is not this question point!!

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for access modifiers?

Comment: Look up when a method is marked as 'protected', which classes/packages are able to access it?

Comment: Please Put executable code inside the method in class Main

Answer (score 2):

[JLS 6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from
>   outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is
>   responsible **for the implementation of that object**.

Being a subclass doesn't mean you are responsible of the implementation.

Here an example, again from the JLS :

```
package points;
public class Point {
    protected int x, y;
    void warp(threePoint.Point3d a) {
        if (a.z > 0)  // compile-time error: cannot access a.z
            a.delta(this);
    }
}
```

```
package threePoint;
import points.Point;
public class Point3d extends Point {
    protected int z;
    public void delta(Point p) {
        p.x += this.x;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.x
        p.y += this.y;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.y
    }
    public void delta3d(Point3d q) {
        q.x += this.x;
        q.y += this.y;
        q.z += this.z;
    }
}
```

> A compile-time error occurs in the method delta here: it cannot access
>   the protected members x and y of its parameter p, because while
>   Point3d (the class in which the references to fields x and y occur) is
>   a subclass of Point (the class in which x and y are declared), it is
>   not involved in the implementation of a Point (the type of the
>   parameter p). The method delta3d can access the protected members of
>   its parameter q, because the class Point3d is a subclass of Point and
>   is involved in the implementation of a Point3d.